# How can I create multiple diagram types in a single Visio document?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-office-2013

I created a Visio document using the UML sequence diagram template. I would like to include a basic flowchart diagram as one of the pages.

How can I do this in the same document while keeping the special template properties of the UML/Flow Charts on the respective pages?

For example, in the UML Sequence templates, arrows that point from right to left will be dashed. In Flow Chart template, arrows automatically turn into right-angle arrows when possible.

I'd like to retain these properties but only on each respective page.

Answer (score 1):

UML contains a suitable diagram type - an activity diagram. If the symbols contained in the activity diagram stencil are not adequate then you can open the flowchart stencil and use those shapes as well, they will work ok.